# What does the Vedas say about non hindus(people who reject vedas) and its philosophy?

Tags: vedas, other-religions

What does vedas say about non Hindus or those who reject vedas and its philosophy?

---

<sup>By philosophy I mean reincarnation, Moksha and karma.</sup>

Comment: there is no pantheism in Hinduism

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda pantheism means a doctrine which identifies God with the universe, or regards the universe as a manifestation of God.. So we say we are the projection of Brahman isn't that pantheism.